# The ListView from Fragment extending ListFragment is repeating itself. Any idea what's wrong?

Tags: java, android

**This is the activity**

```
public class Homepage extends FragmentActivity implements ChatFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

SearchFragment searchFragment;
ChatFragment chatFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

    searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
    chatFragment = new ChatFragment();


    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.homepageFragment,chatFragment).commit();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null){
        //text.setText("user_id: " + bundle.get("user_id") + " ,username: " + bundle.get("username") + " ,password: " + bundle.get("password"));
    }
           super.onResume();
}


@Override
public void onChatFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){

}

public void openSearchFragment(View view){
   if(!searchFragment.isAdded())
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.homepageFragment,searchFragment).commit();
}

public void openChatFragment(View view){
    if(!chatFragment.isAdded())
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.homepageFragment,chatFragment).commit();
    }

    public void openProfile(View view){

    }
}
```

**This is the layout of the activity**

> I like making my activities screen responsive.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="the_activity_location"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/homepageFragment"
            android:name="com.example.summer.toothbrush.SearchFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/whiteClr"
        android:background="@color/whiteClr"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/search_img"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="openSearchFragment"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/chat_img"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="openChatFragment"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_img"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="openProfile"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**This is the fragment**

```
public class SearchFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

ArrayList<String> list;
ListViewAdapter myAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search,container,false);

    list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("I");
    list.add("am");
    list.add("Iron");

    myAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(list,getActivity().getBaseContext());

    setListAdapter(myAdapter);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

**The Layout of the fragment is inside a linear layout consisting of a
 ListView with "@android:id/list" as the ID and a TextView.**

> Don't worry about the adapter. it's working fine.. I tested it out on an activity. Works perfectly fine.

[This is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOfkz.jpg)

Comment: Show `fragment_search ` xml code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. You have two `SearchFragment`. One declared static in your layout, the other added through a `FragmentTransaction`. `Fragment`s declared static in the layout can't be replaced using a programmatically transaction. Just replace

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/homepageFragment"
        android:name="com.example.summer.toothbrush.SearchFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search"/>
```

with

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/homepageFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

and it is going to work as you expect

Comment: Thanks Blackbelt. You saved me.